# VBA check String is matched exactly word

Tags: regex, vba

I use this code below to check if the string is match to pattern or not.

```
Sub chkPattern(str As String, pattern As String) 

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegex.pattern = pattern
    MsgBox objRegex.test(str)

End Sub
```

Specifically, I want to check if string match whole string `"abc" or "cde" of "xy"`

For example, if inputs are "abccde" or "abcxy" or "abccdexyz", I expect it will return false

Some patterns that I have already try like : "abc|cde|xyz" , "\b(abc|cde|xyz)\b)"  are not working

Can this be done in VBA by using Regex?

Comment: Tell what is the string you want to check? And what is desired result?

Comment: Was it `\b(abc|cde|xyz)\b` you tried or did you really have a typo and write the word boundary as `/b`?

Comment: sorry, I edited to /b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible yes. As I read your question you want to apply the `OR` with the pipe character.

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("abc", "cde", "xy")

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "^(" & Join(arr, "|") & ")$"
    Debug.Print .Test("abcd") 'Will return False
    Debug.Print .Test("abc") 'Will return True
End With

End Sub
```

The key to match the *whole* string here are the start string ancor `^`  and the end string ancor `$`. If you meant you wanted to test for *partial* match, you have simply reversed the slashes. Use backslashes instead of forward slashes > `\b(abc|cde|xyz)\b` as a pattern.

Remember, when you want to ignore case comparison, use `.IgnoreCase = True`.

---

Alternatively use the build-in `Like` operator.

Answer (score 0):

\babc\b|\bcde\b|\bxy\b should work for "abc" or "cde" or "xy" but not other variants.

Answer (score 0):

To match whole word use

**`(\w+)`**

https://regex101.com/r/sve6Tp/1

`(\w+)` Capturing Group

`\w+` matches any word character `(equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])`

**`+`** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,

[image]